# how to hide and show a div using media query's

Tags: html, jquery, css

i need to hide this div above 992px and show this div in mobile responsive and tab view

```
 <div class="nav-button but-hol">
                <span  class="nos"></span>
                <span class="ncs"></span>
                <span class="nbs"></span>
                <div id="my-content"></div>
                <div class="menu-button-text">Menu</div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="nav-button but-hol"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
@media (min-width:992px)  {
    .nav-button {
      display:none;}
}
`
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to improve the long term value

Answer (score 1):

`max-width` is for the noted px ans smaller

```css
.navbar {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {
 .navbar{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">hello media</div>
```

Comment: instead of this i can place the calss name right

Comment: לבני מלכה  its not working can you wirte the exact code using the class

Comment: navbar is not my class have you checked my code

Comment: please opne F12 in your browser and in element tab check what happened to your css